# Trying to have button click open new window and load an external URL but running into "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes"

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to this so any help is welcomed! Have built a button on a record page layout that when clicked should open a new window and load a page based off of a URL field on the user profile. Upon clicking the button I am running into the issue stated in the title

> Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.

Not sure what is actually wrong but below is my VF page and apex class.

VF page:

```html
<apex:page StandardController="lead" extensions="CalendlyApexClass" action="{!urlRedirection}">
</apex:page>
```

Apex class

```java
public class CalendlyApexClass {

    public PageReference urlRedirection() {

          string url = '{!Lead.test__c}';

          PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
          page.setRedirect(true);
          return page;
    }

    public CalendlyApexClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a bug. Normally, you'd not use a merge field, but rather just use the value directly.

```
public class CalendlyApexClass {
    Lead record;
    public PageReference urlRedirection() {
        string url = record.Test__c;
        PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
    
    public CalendlyApexClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            stdController.addFields(new String[] { 'Test__c' });
        }
        record = (Lead)stdController.getRecord();
    }
}
```

It looks like in some cases, the Visualforce runtime gets confused. I've tried other kinds of formulas, and they don't seem to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Had a follow up question: The solution works but it seems the URL is not working as intended. The url itself should be pulling in data from the lead to autofill a form but seems that autofill is not happening. Would there need to be any additional code within the apex class? 

For reference the url contains ' ?soSkip=1&sosfLeadId={!Lead.Id}&sosfContactId={!Contact.Id}&sosfCaseId={!Case.Id} ' at the end and when this is used in the button as a content source url instead of a VF page, it pulls in the required data for the form.